# Gmail Contacts on Android refusing to sync 1 specific contact. What could be the reasons?

Tags: contacts, 8.1-oreo

In my android device, I have set my contacts to be sync to my gmail account. I just add contacts under my email address instead of the phone and just assumed that everything will be synced. But now I found 1 contact that just would not sync. No clue why. Contacts created after that and just now before posting all synced, except that one. When I view all email account contacts in android, its 293 while my gmail contacts web-client has just 292. My backup phone which is also synced to Gmail Contacts has 292.

I have no clue why this contact would not sync. What is different about it? But the main question that I wonder is, how many contacts have I lost due to these non-syncing issue and never realised till date.

How do I understand the problem?